# Pandas: Re-assigning values to a 'block' of a Data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Probably a trivial problem, but I need to understand what's going on here (and how to fix it).

Suppose I have a dataframe with columns 'a' and 'b', as follows:

```
f = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[10,20,30,40,50]})
```

Now for every element of 'a' that is 3 or less, I want to divide the corresponding elements of 'b' by 10.

```
f[f['a']<=3]['b'] = (f[f['a']<=3]['b'])/10
```

So that the values in column 'b' should now be [1,2,3,40,50].

But I find that column 'b' remains unchanged! What gives?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192741/understanding-pandas-dataframe-indexing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are trying to assign values to a copy rather than a view (`f[f['a']<=3]['b']` is a copy), see *[Returning a view versus a copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)*.

However, you can reorder this and it'll work be a view:

```
In [11]: f['b'][f['a']<=3] = (f[f['a']<=3]['b'])/10

In [12]: f
Out[12]:
   a   b
0  1   1
1  2   2
2  3   3
3  4  40
4  5  50
```

Comment: To elaborate on Andy's answer, read http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy to understand what is happening.

Comment: @DanAllan was just filling it in with that same link :)

Comment: @AndyHayden, would love to have a couple of more examples in 'Returning a view vs copy' section, as seem to have lots of questions (and confusion) in that regards...

Comment: @Jeff agreed, I will try and put something together. *It is confusing, so it'll be a good thing to write down...*

Answer (score 0):

Like answers just mentioned, its is a copy and view's issue.

And if I want to do this, I may choose this:

```
f['b'] = np.where(f['a'] <= 3, f['b']/10, f['b'])
#f

Out[26]:
a   b
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   4   40
4   5   50
```